# Соединение с сервером. SSMS

Tags: sql-server, сервер

Не могу настроить среду разработки. Вроде делаю все по инструкции как написано у майрософта на сатйе, но ничего не выходит. Пытаюсь создать локальный сервер - при нажатии проверка вылетает ошибка. Толком документации нигде не могу найти. Может кто подсказать что нужно делать, или направить на какую-то конкретную документацию по созданию локального сервера и подключения к нему.

---

P.S. гугл ошибки error: 40, 53 ничем не помог

P.S.S заранее прошу не гореть над этим "простейшим" для Вас вопросом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а при чем тут `mysql` ?

Comment: @teran поправил, не заметил когда добавлял

Comment: У вас в зарегистрированyых 2 сервера в латинским названием, вы уверены, что сервер с названием кирилицей (Нормандия) существует?